# Possible to hide progress text from horizontal style, indeterminate ProgressDialog?

Tags: android-asynctask, android, android-alertdialog, android-progressbar

I am showing a horizontal style, indeterminate ProgressDialog as follows:

```
progressDialog.setMessage("My progress dialog message");
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
progressDialog.show();
```

The indeterminate horizontal progress graphic/animation shows okay. However, give that it's an indeterminate progress dialog, I would expect the "0%" and "0/100" labels on the bottom left and bottom right respectively to be hidden. Anyone know how to hide these?

Comment: It won't work like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Andro Selva's comment, the best I've been able to come up with is to use...

```
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
```

... when it's determinate and to use...

```
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
```

... when it's indeterminate. Not ideal but it works. (The spinner style doesn't show the progress values.)

Comment: This is the right way to go. Indeterminate should not use `STYLE_HORIZONTAL`. Using `STYLE_SPINNER` looks much better and is better suited for this.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to hide those by calling two ProgressDialog's methods

```
progressDialog.setProgressNumberFormat(null);
progressDialog.setProgressPercentFormat(null);
```

See [ProgressDialog documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html#setProgressNumberFormat(java.lang.String)) for reference.

Answer (score 2):

I know this one is a bit old but maybe my answer helps someone else.

To get a progressdialog which is indeterminate WITHOUT the text bolow I did that:

```
ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

Dialog progressDialog = new Dialog(context);
progressDialog.setContentView(progressBar);
```

Hope this helps :)